# Multiple SonarQube analysis on one pull-request

Tags: github, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We used to have a big project that had SonarQube analysis run on it for every pull-request on GitHub. Everything worked fine.

Then we did some refactoring, and split the code into separate projects. Since the code is related, the repo is still the same. But, instead of running just one build+analysis we run multiple ones per pull-request.

Everything else works fine, except that the SonarQube GitHub plugin writes the problems found in the first build, then removes them in the second build and so on. So I get an email about problems in the first build, but when I go and look at the PR in GitHub, it's all green and no messages anywhere.

Optimally I would like to specify to SonarQube GH plugin that these builds should be handled as separate in the PR, but I haven't found a way to do that yet.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible with the SonarQube GitHub plugin. If you want PR analysis back, you have 2 ways:

- Either you gather those projects under the same umbrella, making them modules of a top project
- Or you extract them in different repositories

The best solution depends on how your "new" projects are coupled to each other. If they have the same lifecycle (~ the same versioning scheme), then it's best to gather them under a top project. If not (i.e. they can be released independently with different versions), then moving them to dedicated repositories would be the best approach.

Comment: We've just pushed code into the same repository to get out of PR hell, so we'll likely try the the umbrella solution. But there are many different technologies at play, so it's not going to be fast or easy (or at all possible).

It seems that what I'm asking could be possible, with https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-github/pull/31. Thoughts?

Comment: Do you know if multiple SonarQube analysis on one pull-request is possible in Azure DevOps and [SonarQube Extension for VSTS](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS)

Comment: I checked the open issue in reference to VSTS / Azure DevOps and is active discussion here https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-pull-request-integration-with-multiple-builds/1992

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but requires a complex setup:
- A SonarQube project for each language.
- A Github user for each language
- In each SonarQube project, under the General Settings -> Pull Requests, set a different access token to post back to github for each project.

Now you will have 2 different commenters, one for each project.